# Array Formula to Eliminate the Blank Cells in a Drop Down List

Tags: microsoft-excel

Followed step by step a you tube video, Excel Magic Trick 916: Remove Blanks In Data Validation Drop Down List 5 Examples.  When I hit control>shift>enter, then copy down, all my cells display the SAME name as the first cell, opposed to the DIFFERENT names as in the you tube, that I am trying to achieve.  The only difference is that I am using EXCEL 2013, and I believe they use Excel 2007 in the video. This is the formula I'm using, any idea what's wrong?

```
=IF(ROWS(C$2:C2)>COUNTA($A$2:$A$12),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$12,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$12<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(C$2:C2))))
```

Comment: My guess; copy A2:A12 to C2:... leaving out the gaps in the source. That would mean this formula needs to be in C2 for starters.

Comment: @LDC3 The construction being used is a perfectly good one. And ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$2)+1 is not at all "always 1", since the formula in question is an ARRAY formula, and so this portion returns an ARRAY of values, not just one, equivalent to: {2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}-ROW($A$2)+1, i.e. {2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}-2+1, i.e. {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11}. And, since the OP's formula is designed to be copied down to further cells, ROWS(C$2:C2) is, again, not "always 1", since, in further rows to which this formula is copied, this becomes, successively: ROWS(C$2:C3) (=2), ROWS(C$2:C4) (=3), etc.

Comment: @XORLX Ok, it's my mistake that I didn't watch the video, and I didn't realize that it was an array formula (the OP didn't mention that).

Answer (score 1):

A less complex variant here; type this into cell C2

```
=IFERROR(LARGE($A$2:$A$12;ROWS(C$2:C2)),"")
```

`IFERROR()` checks for errors, and displays the result value in case of no error.
In case of an error, the value given as second argument is displayed instead.

This example removes the need to use an array formula,
and also reverses the order to largest first - replace LARGE() for SMALL() to keep smallest first.
Do "fill down" on it for any number of cells you wish.

Fill in source data in $A$2:$A$12  (enlarge the $A$2:$A$12 range in formula if you wish to expand on it).

Having the TEXT "$A$2:$A$12" in e.g. C1 will make `INDIRECT($C$1)` work as a substitute for `$A$2:$A$12` in the formula.

Comment: You are repreating code here for no reason - it's bad design. Use `=IFERROR(LARGE($A$2:$A$12;ROWS(C$2:C2)),"")`

Comment: Bad design comes from not knowing about every function and trick there is, yes. I have been using Excel for many years, but still find new things - `IFERROR()` is the most recent example of that. You could have chosen words more nicely though. Answer revised.

Comment: +1 for your answer, it's good. Apologies for my phrasing - I didn't mean it the way it reads.

Comment: No offence taken :-)